# calls to `require` expect exactly 1 string literal argument, but this was found:

Tags: image, react-native, react-native-sectionlist

I have component in application with SectionList which parses its content from local json file. List item has image and text and when require image using varibale it causes error: `calls to require expect exactly 1 string literal argument, but this was found: item.logo`.

My json file

```
{
    "algorithms":[
       {"title":"Sorting algorithms","logo":"../logos/sorting.png"},
       {"title":"Graph theory","logo":"../logos/graph.png"},
       {"title":"Strings","logo":"../logos/strings.png"},
       {"title":"Greedy technique","logo":"../logos/greedy.png"},
       {"title":"Dynamic programming","logo":"../logos/dp.png"}
    ],
    "datastructures":[
       {"title":"Trees","logo":"../logos/tree.png"},
       {"title":"Lists","logo":"../logos/list.png"},
       {"title":"Tries","logo":"../logos/trie.png"},
       {"title":"Stack and Queue","logo":"../logos/stack.png"},
       {"title":"Hash Tables","logo":"../logos/hashtable.png"}
     ] 
}
```

And `renderItem` function

```
renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return(
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('List')}>
            <View style={styles.itemHolder}>
                <Image resizeMode="center" style={styles.itemLogo} source={require(item.logo)}/>
                <View style = {styles.itemNameHolder}>
                    <Text style = {styles.itemName}>{item.title}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.itemPointer}>
                    <Image style={{width:50,height:50,}} source={require('../icons/right-arrow.png')}/>
                </View>
                <Divider/>
            </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback> 
    );
}
```

**Edited**

Function `require` in js does not work dynamically. It's argument must be string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: 
I think you need to use a workaround of map

first, you need to find a way to make the logo format to be like this

```
const data = [
   {"title":"Sorting algorithms","logo": require('../logos/sorting.png')},
   {"title":"Graph theory","logo": require('../logos/graph.png')},
]
```

Then when you want to use it just do like this

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      {data.map((item) => {
        <View>
          <Image
           style={styles.image}
           source={item.logo}
          />
        </View>
      })}
    </View>
  );
}
```

let me know if it is work or not

Comment: I think there is a known bug in React Native related to displaying image dynamically using FlatList or SectionList. I will try to edit the answer.